# How can one dockerize a Terminal Gui application to run on Linux

Tags: c#, .net, docker, terminal.gui

I have created a terminal app in C# .NET 6 using [Terminal Gui](https://github.com/gui-cs/Terminal.Gui). I have dockerized it
but for some reason every time i run the container it keeps exiting with 139, after looking at the logs it initially mentioned that it was missing libncursew.so.5/6 then i added apk add ncurses but after that now I'm getting that same 139 exit code but no additional detail in the logs.

Has anyone dockerized a Terminal.Gui app?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not enough information, please post your dockerfile and logs of an app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From you question I assumed that you are trying to dockerize *Terminal.Gui* on an alpine based container (you've mentioned an *apk* package manager).

Here is an example of dockerizing *Terminal.Gui* template app on an alpine linux image:

- Create a template terminal gui app:

  ```bash
  dotnet new --install Terminal.Gui.templates
  dotnet new tui -n myproj
  cd myproj
  dotnet run
  ```
- Publish it, so we'll be able to use it in a container:

  ```bash
  dotnet publish -c Release -r linux-musl-x64 --self-contained
  ```

  - *-r* stands for run *runtime*, this is important since we'll be publishing our binaries on another OS, just to keep things working. This is a must for alpine linux, otherwise it won't work.
  - *--self-contained* means that we won't need to install dotnet framework on a machine where app will run
- Create a dockerfile:

  ```
  FROM alpine:latest
  RUN apk add --no-cache  ncurses musl-dev gcc icu bash
  WORKDIR /app
  COPY ./bin/Release/net6.0/linux-musl-x64/publish/ /app
  CMD bash -c /app/myproj
  ```

  - *ncurses*, *musl-dev*, *gcc*, *icu* and *bash* are requirements of *terminal.gui* lib, I found it out via trial and error. Probably part of this is an overkill and you won't need to install full packages, just a little subset of libraries that come with those packages.
  - published app copied under */app* folder in a container.
- Build an image:

  ```bash
  docker build -t tuiapp .
  ```
- Create and run container:

  ```bash
  docker run --tty --interactive --env TERM tuiapp
  ```

  - *--tty* this is a terminal gui app, have to instruct docker to assigne a pseudo tty
  - *--interactive* otherwise controls won't work
  - *--env* TERM have to pass TERM variable of a shell that invokes docker run. If your environment doesn't have *TERM* env variable set (like in windows terminal for example) you can set it explicitly, like this: ```--env TERM=xterm-256color``, tested it on windows terminal as well.

It should work, tested it on a ubuntu wsl, with tmux and without + tested it on a windows terminal from cmd.

Comment: Mate this is A class service thanks I'll give that a go :)

Comment: Thanks for this it worked just a little tweaks to your response to get it running just the last line in your dockerfile to CMD bash -c /app/myproj and it runs :) thanks heaps